# Would a Raspberry Pi run a Cryptocurrency Mining Pool

Tags: cryptocurrency

I am thinking about setting up a pool for mining cryptocurrency that uses neoscrypt. Would a Raspberry Pi have enough processing power to do this? I would run the Pi 24/7. Would this be reliable?

Comment: Didn't have any energy to do a Google search about RPi crypto mining? It would have yielded about 5 walk-thrus.

Comment: @Chef Flambe Didn't have any energy to thoroughly read my question? I asked about running a pool not mining itself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely,
Each and every computer work for the mining pool and Raspi do work, but the present day question should be asked to whether the investment worth it or not because as the reports show that mining pools that mine on GPU's are barely making profits and also governments are cracking down the exchanges so I would recommend doing some research on returns and when you can expect them.

Comment: Would running a pool be reliable on a RPi?

Comment: Sorry for the delay it depends on which country you are living as of mine even using cryptos has been banned in India and but today cryptos are like gambling prefer to opt for now and do some survey whether you can sustain in the loss.if yes go  ahead but be cautious